# Almost sure convergence of random variables with continuous densities implies $L^1$ convergence of densities?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose we have a sequence of random variables $f_n:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ converging almost surely to some random variable $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Suppose we know that the law of each $f_n$ has a continuous density function $\phi_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ has a continuous density $\phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

I know that almost sure convergence of the random variables implies weak convergence of the laws. Can we use the extra assumptions here to conclude that we have a stronger form of convergence? For example it seems like we should have $\|\phi_n-\phi\|_{L^1}\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: According to the Wikipedia page on convergence of random variables (see the Almost sure representation subsection), given any sequence of r.v. that converge in distribution, you can build another sequence of r.v. (in a different probability space) such that these r.v. converge a.s.. Given this, I think it's unlikely that you can upgrade the convergence: Pick a sequence $\phi_n$ converging weakly but not strongly to $\phi$ on say $[a,b]$ and apply the alluded result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Counterexample**: Consider the prbability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})=([0,\pi],\mathcal{B}([0,\pi]),\frac1\pi\mathrm{Leb})$ and random variables $X_n\colon[0,\pi]\to[0,\pi]$ defined by its inverse
$$
X_n^{-1}(x)=x+\frac{\sin(2nx)}{2 n}
$$
Clearly $X_n$ converges uniformly (hence also almost surely) to the identity $X_\infty\colon[0,\pi]\to[0,\pi]\subset\mathbb{R}$.  But the probability density functions $\phi_n(x)=\frac2\pi\cos^2(nx)$ does not converge in $L^1$ to $\phi_\infty=\frac1\pi 1_{[0,\pi]}$.  Indeed, $\lVert\phi_n-\phi_\infty\rVert_{L^1}=2$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, very helpful. I wasn't thinking about examples likes this. Do you know of any condition which would ensure the L^1 convergence? It seems like we might need something like equicontinuity of the sequence of density functions. I now realise that the almost sure condition is kind of irrelevant.

Comment: You are basically asking for convergence in the [total variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures), or you could use the [Hellinger distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger_distance) since $d_H^2\leq d_{TV}\leq \sqrt2 d_H$.

Comment: Yeah so I'm basically asking when can weak convergence of measures be upgraded to total variation convergence. That's clarified things a bit even if i don't know the answer

Comment: For some class of distributions we can upgrade for free.  Probably most well-known is Ibragimov's theorem: if the densities $\varphi_n,\varphi_\infty$ are unimodal then convergence in distribution implies convergence in total variation.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer above.
I will put my idea for completness - it follows the same approach.

Take a sequence of discrete r.v. converging a.s. but not in L1.
It easy to find it, for example leveraging Borel-Cantelli.

Then add an independent, absolutely continuous r.v..

Adding an independent a.c.r.v. to any r.v. yields an a.c.r.v..

Finally the sequence of the sum converges a.s. to an a.c.r.v., but not in L1.

Comment: I don't think that works.  Let $Y_n$ be $0$ with probability $1-2^{-n}$ and $10^n$ with probabiltiy $2^{-n}$.  Then $Y_n$ converges a.s. to $0$ but doesn't converge in $L^1$.  Add a $U[0,1]$ and you have densities $\phi_n=(1-2^{-n})1_{[0,1]}+2^{-n}1_{[10^n,10^n+1]}$ which converges to $1_{[0,1]}$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood, the random variables you get from the sum will not have continuous density functions so this doesn't fit my conditions

Comment: @GeorgeCh94 The sum of an absolutely continuous rv with a discrete rv, assuming independence, is absolutely continuous because you just use the absolutely continuous rv's density in the convolution.  However, this example doesn't work for the reason I indicated above, probably because Kolmo confused $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with $L^1(X_*\mathbb{P})$.

Comment: Correct. I thought L1 convergence was needed and not of the pdf.